# Components in Django

Tags: django, django-templates, components, reusability

I have a latest news block on a page. It's a piece of markup in a template and some logic fetching the last *n* news in a view.
How can I make a reusable component of it (like some CMS have) which I can include in a template like this:

```
{% component "latest_news" "5" %}
```

for building a block with 5 last news.

Seems [Inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags) is quite good for this purpose, but I wonder may be is there some build-in component-like feature in Django?

Comment: you need to make your own custom template tag, lookup how to make simple_tag's

Comment: Inclusion tags *are* the built-in component-like feature. Django is not a CMS, it's a tool for building applications including CMSs, so that's the closest functionality it gives you.

Comment: OK, thanks, Daniel, I needed to make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest to CMS's components functionality in Django is [Inclusion tags](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#inclusion-tags)

Comment: Is this still accurate in 2018?

Comment: Yes, so far as I know. I found this question looking for a way to organise my code so that the Include templates and the context data they need and the views called can be repacked at will. I think in Django this division only naturally happens at the app level, but a site/project is intended to be a construct with a number of 'apps'. I'm getting along with a template architecture resembling this: https://oncampus.oberlin.edu/webteam/2012/09/architecture-django-templates

Comment: Since Django 2.0, it is also possible to specify a renderer and a template specific to each form. I haven't played around with this, but forms occupy the right sort of space in Django to allow you to generate part of a DOM, rather than a full page. This would perhaps allow an architecture heavy on forms to make the 'views' very flexibly present components.

Answer (score 2):

In 2021, I have come across the following projects:

- https://pypi.org/project/django-render-partial/
- https://pypi.org/project/django-components/

I have used `django-render-partial` pretty extensively, and I like that the interface allows your partials to be used in templates, or hooked directly up to a `urls.py`.

`django-components` looks pretty cool, because it allows you to package CSS and JS files with the use of a `Media` class (similarly to Django forms), but it fractures the "everything is a view" pattern provided by `django-render-partial`.

Answer (score 1):

I used [django_components](https://github.com/EmilStenstrom/django-components) which saved me a lot of pain, it supports creating reusable components with dynamic components name, and it also allows passing HTML fragments to the components.

Answer (score 0):

It was useful for me to learn about [django-simple-components](https://github.com/paqstd-dev/django-simple-components).

Here small example:

```html
# file: templates/myapp/latest_news.html

{% load simple_components %}

{% set_component "article" %}
    <div class="card">
        <img src="{{ image }}" />
        <h3>{{ title }}</h3>
        <p>{{ description }}</p>
    </div>
{% end_set_component %}

<div class="news-list">
    {% component "article"
        image="https://..."
        title="Some lines"
        description="Other text..."
    %}

    {% component "article" image="https://..." title="Second Post" description="Second description..." %}
</div>
```